# toolkit assembly giving error message windows phone

Tags: windows-phone-7, datepicker, silverlight-toolkit, assembly-references

I am developing an app that uses DatePicker and LoopSelector at same time.
Looking on the tutorials for each of them I have been advised to add assembly references, first one for DatePicker and second one for Loopselector:

```
xmlns:toolkit="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit"

xmlns:toolkit="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.ControlsPrimitives;assembly=Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit"
```

and then I get error message saying `The type 'toolkit:Selector' wasn't found.`

I welcome any ideas. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot have the same name ("toolkit") for both of them!

Comment: Yes, thanks for that...I changed one of them to toolkitPrimitives and it works perfectly fine...Thanks so much